# action_up doesn't call after action_move

Tags: android, android-animation, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have an animation that makes a button press down on touch. I want it to be able to stay pressed down, while the user scrolls the screen. To do this, I made an animation that basically just keeps the image in the same state to call in the ACTION_MOVE. My problem is that when I release the button, the ACTION_UP isn't being called which is what triggers the animation to bring the button back to it's full size and no longer looking pressed. I have the entire relative layout inside a ScrollView. I still don't understand fully what's happening, but it appears that the ScrollView may be "taking over" the onTouch events. Here is my code for the onTouchListener.

```
s104.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                clearAnim();
                s104.setAnimation(animPressed);
                s104.startAnimation(animPressed);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                s104.setAnimation(animDrag);
                s104.startAnimation(animDrag);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                s104.setAnimation(animReleased);
                s104.startAnimation(animReleased);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I can't figure out why the ACTION_UP isn't being called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

> I still don't understand fully what's happening, but it appears that the ScrollView may be "taking over" the onTouch events.

That is correct. What you are experiencing is the `ScrollView` "taking over" the `MotionEvent`. You can capture this event in your `OnTouchListener` - add a case for `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL`. In there you can determine the outcome if the user has pressed the View (ACTION_DOWN) and subsequently scrolled down.